# not equals to operator for when condition not working -XSLT

Tags: xslt

How to write when condition using both equals to and not equals to operators at the same time ?
I have written like below but not equals to operator is not working.

```
<xsl:choose>
       <xsl:when test="$storeid='1' and $storeid='2' and ($Type!= 'B1' or $Type!= 'B8') and ($Status='B11' or  $Status='B21')"> 
            <xsl:copy-of select="."/>
         </xsl:when> 
         <xsl:otherwise>
            Do Nothing
         </xsl:otherwise>
      </xsl:choose>
```

Edit: Sorry I was not clear in the post. I'm getting codes in the incoming request. I'm storing them in variables and trying to write conditions.

Sample Input:

```
<soap-env:Envelope
xmlns:soap-env="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"
>

    <soap-env:Header/>
  <soap-env:Body>
  <Header>
  <Store>
  <storeid>1</storeid>
  <storeid>2</storeid>
  </Store>
  <Status>B11</Status>  
<Type>B1</Type>
                        <Book>ABC</Book>
                        <ID>123B</ID>
                        <Address>Address</Address>
</Header>
</soap-env:Body>
</soap-env:Envelope
```

I want to copy the output only If `<Type>` contains codes -B1 or B8, status as - B11 or B21 otherwise reject and storeid should always contain 1 and 2. All of these conditions should be satisfied.

I tried,

```
<xsl:if test="$Type!= 'B1'">
<xsl:choose>
<xsl:when test="$storeid='1' and $storeid='2' and ($Status='B11' or  $Status='B21')"> 
                <xsl:copy-of select="."/>
             </xsl:when> 
             <xsl:otherwise>
                Do Nothing
             </xsl:otherwise>
          </xsl:choose>
</xsl:if>
```

If condition is failing...in this case.
In some cases I need to satisfy only Type !=B1 and in some cases for both B1 and B8 codes in incoming request.

Comment: *"not working"* is not a good description of a problem. I am guessing you are using `or` instead of `and`, but without a [mcve] that's all I can do - guess.

Comment: Looking at your conditions in your test, how can the $storeid variable be equal to '1' and '2' at the same time? Same thing for $Status variable, it can't be equal to both 'B11' and 'B21'? Are those variables refering to a sequence? Is your XSLT engine XSLT 2.0 compliant?

Answer (score 3):

You haven't shown us what's in the variables.

Rather surprisingly perhaps,

```
$storeid='1' and $storeid='2'
```

can be true, for example when the value of `$storeid` is the sequence (1, 2). But it would be a little odd to name the variable `storeid` if it can hold a sequence of integers. So I suspect that's not what you intended.

The expression

```
$Type!= 'B1' or $Type!= 'B8'
```

seems even less plausible. If $Type is an empty sequence, then the result will be false (because `()!='B1'` is false, and `()!='B1'` is also false). In all other cases the expression will be true: today is either not Monday, or it's not Tuesday.

Of course, you haven't told us what you intended the code to do, only that it didn't do what you intended. Without knowing what you wanted it to do, we can't help you put it right.

Comment: Sorry..I have made my post clear now. Please check and advice.